# Position an HTML element by center

Tags: html, css

What's the proper way to position an HTML element according to a center handle?

In this example:

```
  XXXXXXXXX
      |
      |
     123px
```

Assume the element should be position at absolute position `left: 123px;` but the text should be **centered** at that point, not start at it. The element text is dynamic, so I have no way of setting a static negative `margin-left` on it.

Is there a pure CSS way to achieve this? The JS way of measuring `offsetWidth` and then setting `left` after calculating `width / 2` won't neccesarily work in my case due to various limitations.

Comment: maybe use negative margins...this technique will center your content...perhaps you can also apply another negative margin to the text to get it centered as you like: http://web.archive.org/web/20050204013909/http://bluerobot.com/web/css/center2.html

Comment: Try to add jsfiddle to your post ^_^ !

Comment: @albert see my update, it's a dynamic element

Comment: i figured as much, but wanted to throw that technique out there. there's probably a way to achieve what you want. do what @Microsmsm said and create a fiddle for us to tinker with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly easy to achieve that and there are several ways to do it. Since you didn't post any HTML construct for your example, I'll just make up some.

The trick is to have an inline-block parent element which has the desired offset (123px) and inside that element you'll have another inline-block element with a left margin of -50%. Position both relative and you'll have the effect you are looking for.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
}
#line {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 123px;
  position: absolute;
  border-left: 1px solid red;
}
#text {
  left: 123px;
  top: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
#text p {
  position: relative;
  background: green;
  margin-left: -50%;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="line">
 &lt;-- 123px
</div>
<div id="text">
<p>
This is some dynamic text<br>the div has no absolute set width.
</p>
</div></div>
```

There are other ways as mentioned, probably depends on your general layout/HTML structure. I would definitely take a look at the flex-box properties, this might also be suitable here.

If you want to play around with it, here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kc8rpjyw/).

Comment: Thanks Paul, I reached this method indepedently, but it definitely works!

Answer (score 4):

One posibility is to set a transform translateX -50%

```css
p {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
      left: 100px;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<p>ONE</p>
<br>
<p>TWO, LONGER</p>
<br>
<p>THREE, the longest</p>
```

Comment: Good solution. I didn't know about  translateX

Answer (score 1):

Some of various ways to do this with css:

If your element is a block:

```
.element{
    width: 200px; /* Full width */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -100px; /* Half width */
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

or, if you're using **css3**:

```
.element{
    width: 200px; /* Full width */
    left: calc(50% - 100px);
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

You can also have a **non-absolute** approach, but **the parent element position should be relative**:

```
.element-parent{
    position: relative;
}

.element-parent .element{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

If you use text-oriented element (inline-block), this works with IE 7+:

```
.element-parent{
    text-align: center;
}

.element-parent .element{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Read the question *.Assume the element should be position at absolute position left: 123px; but the text should be centered at that point, not start at it. The element text is dynamic, so I have no way of setting a static negative margin-left on it.*

Comment: @dippas In this case, I think `margin: 0 auto;` will work well. ^^